# How to implement NOT IN without establishing relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, icriteria

This is similar to this question: [NHibernate - Implement "NOT IN" query using ICriteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168686/nhibernate-implement-not-in-query-using-icriteria)

But that doesn't work for my solution.

I have an Order:

```
class Order
{
   DateTime CreatedDate { get; set;} 
   Person CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

and a Person:

```
class Person
{ 
   string Name { get; set;} // etc.
}
```

I want to retrieve all people that *don't* have orders within a date range.  The SQL would end up like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT PersonId
                 FROM Order
                 WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31')
```

When I query with the solution provided in the above question, it fails if there are 2100 people or more (SQL won't allow that many parameters).

Also I can't add a Orders collection to person because that would involve pulling *way* too much data (I only want a date range).

How can I do this with NHibernate?

Comment: I would have been fine with HQL but the queries are more maintainable.  From what I understand, SQL won't let you easily map your query to an entity with NHibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery...

```
var peopleWithOrdersInRange = QueryOver.Of<Order>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.CreatedDate).IsBetween(fromDate).And(toDate)
    .SelectGroup(x => x.CreatedBy.Id);

var results = Session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).NotIn(peopleWithOrdersInRange)
    .List();
```

this will produce that exact SQL (with addition of group by people id in the subquery)

Answer (score 2):

> When I query with the solution provided in the above question, it fails if there are 2100 people or more (SQL won't allow that many parameters).

As I understand you do materialize persons with orders collection before passing it into a query.

Here is a linq query that should work

```
var unwantedPersons = 
   from order in session.Query<Order>()
   where order.CreatedDate >= startDate && 
         order.CreatedDate <= endDate
   select order.CreatedBy.Id // NOTE: do not add .ToList() or .ToArray() here.
                             // It *should be* IQueryable<Person> 

var personsWitoutOrders = 
    (from person in session.Query<Person>()
     where !unwantedPersons.Contains(person.Id)
     select person).ToArray();
```

Comment: this looks like a great solution except IQueryable<T> doesn't have a Contains method.

Comment: Are you sure [Queryable.Contains<TSource> Method (IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641)?

Comment: Forgive me; Resharper had me confused.  The real problem is that it's expecting a IQueryable<Person> in the where clause of the second linq statement.

Comment: The error: cannot convert from 'NHibernate.IQueryOver<Person>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<long>'

Comment: You are trying to mix QueryOver and Linq APIs. Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11852245/259946